# 802.11n with ath9k: only 90 Mb/s

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros

I have Atheros device for Wi-Fi (ath9k), the router is a Dlink DSL-2750B. I have configured the router only for 802.11n but I don't have 300Mb/s.

This is the `iwconfig` output

```
 wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Skynet"  
           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: EC:22:80:E7:12:C5   
           Bit Rate=90 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
           Power Management:off
           Link Quality=51/70  Signal level=-59 dBm  
           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
           Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:1506   Missed beacon:0
```

Well, I have only 90Mb/s then 300 Mb/s. Why?

The `iwlist` output is

```
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: EC:22:80:E7:12:C5
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=55/70  Signal level=-55 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Skynet"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000005bb81c86
                    Extra: Last beacon: 88ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0006536B796E6574
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 0B050200840000
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A7E1817FFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D16060D1600000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: Unknown: 7F03010008
                    IE: Unknown: DD8B0050F204104A0001101044000101103B00010310470010B153DDA8147064766CE1DB27D13EF54A10210013442D4C696E6B20436F72706F726174696F6E2E1023000944534C2D32373530421024000631323334353610420004313233341054000800060050F20400011011000944534C2D3237353042100800020004103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180202000C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
```

How can I have a bit rate like the standard 300Mb/s?

Comment: What standard 300 MB/s? I'm pretty sure you need 5GHz for that, and you seem to have only 2.4GHz support.

Comment: You may have a poor wireless connection, or your network card is a bottleneck. Are you using a bga instead of a bgn card? If your router and netcard support it (which it seems) then it's probably a connection issue.  Edit: i just checked. Wireless N supports speeds up to 600 Mbps total. You're probably using b, g, or a.

Comment: @waterlubber The router has been set to use only n. My card has b,g,n. I can't understand the reason why the chipse doesn't work about 300Mb/s. Router spec said "Up to 300 Mbps (802.11n)"

Comment: @lunatic84 your wifi card needs to be 5GHz for that. It isn't.

Comment: @muru you had right how can I set 5Ghz if the router doesn't have 5Ghz?

Comment: I think ath9k driver doesn't support 802.11n

Comment: O.o think about what you are asking. Neither your router nor your wifi card have 5GHz support. The advertised 300 Mbps speed is obtained by MIMO - your wifi card needs to have two antennae for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

`sudo -i
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1 ps_enable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
modprobe -r ath9k
modprobe ath9k nohwcrypt=1
modprobe ath9k ps_enable=1`

Reboot your system to take effect.