# Can we increase Ubuntu's WiFi performance?

Tags: networking, ath9k

My modem is kept few meters away from where I regularly use my laptop. When I do work in Ubuntu the WiFi gets disconnected frequently; I've to spend a lot of time reconnecting. But using the same machine at the same spot in Windows 10 this problem doesn't occur. So I think that Ubuntu isn't using my hardware well.

**Requested lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 output:**

```
 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01) Subsystem: AzureWave QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:213a] Kernel driver in use: ath9k Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: First of all make sure you're using the recommended wireless encryption settings, at the router: WPA2-AES only, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Then, if the problem persists, it's hardware specific and we need to know which.

Comment: @Pilot6 
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01) Subsystem: AzureWave QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:213a]
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k
 Kernel modules: ath9k

Comment: Try turning off power management for your wifi card: [How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on) . This helped my connection stay stable.

Comment: @CelticWarrior WPA2/TKIP encryption.

Comment: @NickWeinberg What difference will make from turning power management off?

Comment: Well, it might use a bit more power (and reduce battery life), but might also result in a more stable and reliable wifi connection. It helped my connection; you would have to try it for yourself to see if you get similar results.

Comment: Changed encryption and turned off power management, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/627340/802-11n-with-ath9k-only-90-mb-s